# Have history registered in browser with user search results?

Tags: feature-request

I noticed something today when I was searching for a particular user on SO today. The user I searched for had ~25 results. I could not determine which user was the correct one so I had to click on their name to investigate. When I would see it was not the user I was looking for I pressed the back button (Chrome).

The problem was the page I was returned to was the default 'all users' page and I would have to search for the name again to get the short list, and repeat this process over and over.

My guess is some partial rendering might be occurring and the 'search results' does not register as a page in the browser's history. Thus when pressing the 'back' button I went all the way back to the main 'users' page. I'm sure my hunting for users is not unusual so having the results page be in the history would be really convenient.

Is there a way the results list that have been filtered can be registered as a page in the browser's history (or equivalent tweak) so that I can check a user's profile and then press back to see my filtered results without having to do the search all over again?

**EDIT:** I think for most web sites where a search is preformed, there is either a `Back to search results` link or simply pressing the back button does this. Think of eBay or Amazon for example. It would be a lot of extra work for the user's to continually have to enter the same search criteria over and over.

Comment: Hold ctrl/cmd and open the results in new tabs.

Comment: Or if your mouse has a middle button, middle click to open in a new tab.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. That's more along the lines of a browser interaction technique, as opposed to embedded functionality. I made an edit.

Comment: I think this is a reasonable request. I'd like to see it done. I think better support for browser navigation is definitely something SO should consider :)